# jquery-2.1.1.min.js causes mixed content error in opencart 2.0.2.0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, https, opencart

I've come across a rather strange problem.

While making sure that our e-shop (OpenCart 2.0.2.0) located at https://bioma.cz is fully protected by https, it gave me the following error in console (Ctrl+Shift+K):

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content: "http://www.bioma.cz/image/catalog/loga/bio_vlajka.png"
```

I checked the page source with Ctrl+U to see that the URL begins with https in the page source (and there is no http:// string in the whole source). There is no http:// string anywhere in the *.tpl files from which the main page is generated.

I realized that it must be (or very likely is) related to the OpenCart's HTML Content Module, as this is the only part of our site that refers to **image/catalog/loga/bio_vlajka.png**.

While opening the HTML Content Module for editing in OpenCart's administration, the console gives me the same error, however, in the right column of the console, it refers now to **admin/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js** (line 3, character 16159).

I checked the file on the server (VPS with CentOS 6.10) and the script is too complicated for my very limited knowledge of Javascript. The part of the file around the character 16159 on line 3:

```
b.nodeType&&(n.cleanData(ob(b,!1)),b.innerHTML
```

I even tried to replace occurrences of "http:" with "https:" in the script, which didn't help, so I reverted the script to the original version.

In my config.php I have:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.bioma.cz/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.bioma.cz/');
```

In my admin/config.php I have:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.bioma.cz/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://www.bioma.cz/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.bioma.cz/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.bioma.cz/');
```

In the bioma.cz section of my /etc/httpd/conf.d/directory.conf, I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong? How do I prevent the jquery script from loading content over HTTP and make it load it over HTTPS instead?

Thank you very much

Petr Břeň

Comment: So it appears they are spitting out http instead of https....

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had an error in my directory.conf syntax before the lines I posted here.

The whole block is now like this:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.bioma.cz$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.bioma.cz/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

and I have a green padlock:).